# Why do I get a faulty Fourier coefficient here?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

My starting point is cosine on $[0, 2\pi)$ represented by a projection onto the function space with basis

$$
\{ \cos(0), \sin(0), \cos(x), \sin(x), \cos(2x) \sin(2x), ...\}
$$

given by

$$
\cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \;\langle\cos(x), \cos(kx)\rangle\frac{\cos(kx)}{ \|\cos(kx)\|^2} + \langle\cos(x), \sin(kx)\rangle\frac{\sin(kx)}{\|\sin(kx)\|^2},
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
\langle\cos(x), \cos(kx)\rangle &= \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos(x) \cos(kx) dx \\
&= \left.\frac{\sin((k - 1)x)}{2(k - 1)} + \frac{\sin((k + 1)x)}{2(k + 1)}\right|_0^{2\pi} = 0, \text{if} \; k \neq 1,
\end{align}
$$

is the inner product, and

$$
\|\cos(kx)\|^2 = \langle\cos(kx), \cos(kx)\rangle = \pi
$$

normalizes $\cos(kx)$ terms.

Now, if I use a Riemann approximation

$$
\langle\cos(x), \cos(kx)\rangle \approx \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \cos(x) \cos(kx) \Delta x,
$$

and introduce

$$
x = 2\pi j/N, \; \Delta x = 2\pi / N,
$$

I am getting

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \cos(x) \cos(kx) \Delta x = 2\pi/N \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \cos(j2\pi/N) \cos(jk2\pi/N).
$$

Due to the following identity

\begin{align}
\cos(j2\pi/N) &= \cos(-j2\pi/N) \\
&= \cos(-j2\pi/N + j2\pi) \\
&= \cos(j2\pi(1 - 1/N)) = \cos(j2\pi(N-1)/N)
\end{align}

we have that

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \cos(x) \cos(x) \Delta x = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \cos(x) \cos((N-1)x) \Delta x,
$$

which means that the approximated Fourier coefficients $a_1$ and $a_{N-1}$ are the same.

But the function $\cos(x) = 1 \cdot \cos(1 \cdot x)$ should
have Fourier coefficients $a_1 = \pi$ and $a_k = 0, k \neq 1$.

Comment: $N$ is not fixed but it depends on your partition; for the Riemann sum you need $N \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

The described phenomenon is a direct consequence of the finite approximation of the Fourier coefficients and commonly referred to as [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions).